# How to replace the single quote ( ' ) into double quotes ( " ) in Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

I have a List, items are created by append by a Loop. I want to use this list as a json. The problem is that the items of that list use the single quote so it can't be the json.

```
Get Order Items
    [Tags]    Get Order Items
    Set Headers    ${HEADER CUSTOMER}
    GET            ${ORDER GET BY CODE ENDPOINT}/${ORDER CODE}
    Integer        response status    200
    ${NUMBER OF ITEMS}    Output     $.number_of_items
    ${NUMBER OF ITEMS}    Evaluate  ${NUMBER OF ITEMS} + 1
    ${ORDER ITEMS}     Create List    
    :FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE  1  ${NUMBER OF ITEMS}
    \    Append To List    ${ORDER ITEMS}    ${ORDER CODE}${i}  
    Set Global Variable    ${ORDER ITEMS}
```

Actual result: ['N19072596HB1', 'N19072596HB2', 'N19072596HB3', 'N19072596HB4', 'N19072596HB5']

Expected result: ["N19072596HB1", "N19072596HB2", "N19072596HB3", "N19072596HB4", "N19072596HB5"]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This: ['N19072596HB1', 'N19072596HB2', 'N19072596HB3', 'N19072596HB4', 'N19072596HB5'] , is python's string representation of a list, and they have picked to use single quotes for it.

As your end goal is to use the double-quoted version in a json, the best bet is to use the python's `json` library to convert it for you, instead of replacing single with double quotes:

```
${list as string}=    Evaluate    json.dumps($ORDER_ITEMS)    json
```

*(note how the variable is **not** surrounded by curly brackets - thus you're passing the actual variable to the method, not its value)*

Why not to use a simple string replacement?
Because you don't want to deal with cases where a list member may have a quote, single or double - like ['N19072596HB1', "N1907'2596HB2", 'N19072596HB1', 'N19072"596HB2'].
A trivial string replace will fail miserably, while the `json` library is designed to handle these cases as expected.